# How to setting up rtl8187 on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have tried to install the realtek drivers for the ALFA AWUS036H with no results.

Recently I read that the driver from realtek doesn't work. There is any way to use the internal driver that comes into ubuntu or fedora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a couple of The Realtek Wireless Adapter rtl8187 and as I've used them you do not need to install any driver both for normal usage or anything else on Linux distributions whether it's Ubuntu, Fedora or Debian and Kali Linux.

Comment: But each time I plug the card and I try to open a web page, firefox doesn't connect, but in the monitor shows that the connectios is working. What happens?

Comment: well it appears that the Wireless adapter is working as it should because it's connected to the router but no internet. there may be a problem with internet connection or there are more than one active connection. are you using a Virtual machine or VMware?

Comment: I dont't think so. When I connect the card to the guest, I can browse the web, but in the fedora vmware there isnt internet

Comment: if you're using vmware, open up the settings page for your fedora virtual machine and in the networking section disable any internet connection to the Virtual machine like NAT etc. and then connect your USB wireless adapter using removable devices option in the top menu of the virtual machine so that the only internet connection to the virtual machine will be through the USB wireless adapter. then try to ping Google to make sure.     ping -c 4 google.com

Comment: The problem is resolved!, thanks, but I have the same problem with fedora in dual boot. Do you know why?

Comment: well at least you know that the driver or wireless adapter is not the cause of no internet connection. did you try to ping Google in fedora?

Comment: yes but didn't work. Maybe the problem could be that the virtual machine is updated and the dual boot not. Let me try again.

Comment: No, the ping command doesn't work. I tried to deactivate the pci adapter in order to let the alfa usb alone but both turned off. Maybe I need to update fedora. What do you think?

Comment: try to connect your wireless adapter directly to the USB ports at the back of your main board. and yes if you have to use fedora try to download newest iso file and do a clean install.

Comment: Then I'm going to reinstall it. Do you know if is the same problem in ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu is the most favorite Linux distribution for general purposes and is often updated. there's no problem using that Wireless adapter on Ubuntu. i personally prefer using VMware for other OSs other than windows. but let me ask you, why do you want to have both fedora and Ubuntu and use that particular Wireless adapter ?